# How to change from electronic session to regular for standard tickerid fore future index

Tags: pine-script

I have the following code `[closes,opens,lows,highs] = request.security(ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [close,open,low,high])` 
Which is using for future idex `ES1!`.

This will basically get the electronic data for standard chart.

Is there a way to change that code to get the `ticker.standard` for the `Regular Hours` for standard chart?
In other words, I want to do exactly the same thing as my code, only in the regular session.